# Dynamic multicast in AWS not working using IGMPv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, multicast, tomcat8

I have a java application running on tomcat on multiple ec2 instances, and I want to deploy it in cluster mode which is working when I configure in each tomcat server a `StaticMembershipInterceptor` for the other instances. But this is not a viable solution since I want to use auto scaling, and I don't want to modify each time the server.xml

So I try to use `McastService` on ip address `224.0.0.4` to run a multicast address, and have the same configuration on all instances, I also configured on my VPC the following

- a transit Gateway with the attribute Multicast support Enabled
- a transit gateway attachement linked to my VPC and my 2 private subnets
- a transit gateway multicast domain with IGMPv2 support enabled, and associated to my subnets using the TG attachement
- on the security group of my instances I've enabled all traffic in the local network

on my ec2 instances I disabled the check source/Dest and forced IGMP to version 2, but I still can't get multicasting working, I try to ping the multicast address but all packets are lost.

when running the command `ip maddr show eth0` on an instance after launching tomcat with multicast membership I get:
[image]

Is there another configuration I'm missing ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my instances from t2.micro to t3.micro and it worked, the multicast with igmp works only for nitro instances